# Jenkins can't fetch data from remote bitbucket Git repo

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins 2.45, Git - 1.7.0.4

Command line:
git clone https://my_account@bitbucket.org/my_project.git

It's success cloned remote Git repo. OK!

My Jenkinks job config (on the same machine)

[image]

But when I run job, the Jenkins can't fetch data from remote bitbucket Git repo. Throw time out after 10 min

[image]